# Send visitor to new page after Drag and Drop

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui

I want to send a visitor to a new page after they drag three coins into three different jars, but I am unsure of how to trigger the new page after they drag the coins into the jars. 
I'm hoping that something like this will work:
http://jsfiddle.net/F8L44/

```
$(init);
function init() {
    $('#makeMeDraggable1').draggable();
    $('#makeMeDroppable1').droppable({
        drop: function () {
            $("#makeMeDraggable1").draggable("option", "containment", "#makeMeDroppable1");
        }
    });
    $('#makeMeDraggable2').draggable();
    $('#makeMeDroppable2').droppable({
        drop: function () {
            $("#makeMeDraggable2").draggable("option", "containment", "#makeMeDroppable2");
        }
    });
    $('#makeMeDraggable3').draggable();
    $('#makeMeDroppable3').droppable({
        drop: function () {
            $("#makeMeDraggable3").draggable("option", "containment", "#makeMeDroppable3");
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(init);

function init () {
    var drops = 0,
        redirectIfDone = function () {
            if (drops === 3) {
                window.location = 'http://www.google.com';
            }
        };

    $('#makeMeDraggable1').draggable();
    $('#makeMeDroppable1').droppable({
        drop: function () {
            drops++;
            redirectIfDone();
            $("#makeMeDraggable1").draggable("option", "containment", "#makeMeDroppable1");
        }
    });
    $('#makeMeDraggable2').draggable();
    $('#makeMeDroppable2').droppable({
        drop: function () {
            drops++;
            redirectIfDone();
            $("#makeMeDraggable2").draggable("option", "containment", "#makeMeDroppable2");
        }
    });
    $('#makeMeDraggable3').draggable();
    $('#makeMeDroppable3').droppable({
        drop: function () {
            drops++;
            redirectIfDone();
            $("#makeMeDraggable3").draggable("option", "containment", "#makeMeDroppable3");
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This is for a children's exhibit at a museum, so the kids will be very grateful.

Comment: No worries! I am glad that I could help :)